# c++ vector insert Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, vector, stl

My vectors are constructed like this:

```
struct segment {
    float x1;
    float y1;
    float x2;
    float y2;
    float k;
    float b;
};

enum EventType {UPPER_PT = 0, LOWER_PT, INTER_PT};
struct order {
    float x;
    float y;
    vector<segment>::iterator line_id;
    vector<segment>::iterator line2_id;
    EventType type;
};

vector<segment> seg_lines;
vector<order> event_list;
```

After initializing `event_list`, I try to `insert()` a new element at random position like this:

```
order new_event;
new_event.x = 300;
new_event.y = 400;
new_event.line_id = an_iterator_in_seg_lines;
new_event.line2_id = another_iterator_in_seg_lines;
new_event.type = INTER_PT;

bool inte_inserted = false;
for(vector<order>::iterator tmp_idx = event_list.begin(); tmp_idx != event_list.end(); tmp_idx++) {
    if(a_Y_threshold > tmp_idx->y || a_Y_threshold == tmp_idx->y && an_X_threshold < tmp_idx->x) {
        event_list.insert(tmp_idx, new_event);
        inte_inserted = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

I can assure you that `line_id` and `line2_id` are both valid. I'm just trying to simplify my description.

In this case, it's trying to insert a `new_event` at the "5th position", while the size and capacity of `event_list` are both 10 and the `event_list` is full of valid `order`.

But I get such error:

```
Unhandled exception in ... 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000
```

I think the error code tells me that I'm using an invalid pointer. But I checked my 'Watch' view, and all iterators related (including `tmp_idx`) are all valid and pointing to the right positions.

I try to use `emplace()` instead of `insert()`, it doesn't work. I tried to `resize()` my `event_list` before inserting new element, it doesn't work either. But when I use `list` to construct `event_list` instead of `vector`, it works like a charm.

So, what may have caused this problem and what should I do if I want to stick with `vector`?

I'm using VS 2010.

Comment: insert (might) trigger a new allocation and invalidate all iterators/pointers - use indices

Comment: When you insert into a vector, it may reallocate its buffer, causing all iterators into it to become invalid. In particular, `line_id` and `line2_id` being invalid could be your problem.  Using `list` fixes this because iterators are not invalidated by inserting into a list.

Comment: The suspicious part of your code are the two iterators that are members of your order class.  Insertion into a vector may cause iterators to become invalidated.

Comment: The actual code you've posted seems OK however you may already have caused UB earlier in the code and it happens to show up at this point.

Comment: If this is the problem and you want to stick with vector, you could store intger offsets instead of iterators

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks. Your explanation and advice sound very convincing to me. I'll give you a tip after trying this:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)

> If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references related to the container are invalidated.

You are inserting while looping on a vector, which may invalidate your iterators.
You could push back elements into the vector instead of inserting them, and only at  the end reorder the vector. Much easier and cleaner.

Comment: ... and use indices instead of iterators

Comment: Iterators are the way to go, it will be easier to switch from a stl container to another.